# IF statement to display cell information

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula for this spreadsheet,
if cell a2 is greater than 0 then display the information from a new sheet and the cell f9

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, 
This may help you;

```
=IF(A2>0,Sheet2!F9,"")
```

Or

```
 =IF(A2>0,Sheet2!$F$9,"")
```

Sheet2 is the name of the next sheet from where you will pull information.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, I have another question how to update the formula with the if  A2 is blank and it display the formula

Comment: I have the formula for this spreadsheet, if cell a2 is greater than 0 then display the information from a new sheet and the cell f9, but I also need to put in the if statement if the cell is blank then dont display any information. Can this formula be done . 

this is the first half of the formula to show if the cell is less greater than zero to display the information on the other sheet from cell F9, the help I need is to update the formula to say If A2 is blank then leave the cell blank. 
=IF(A2>0,Sheet2!F9,"")

Comment: Try this, =IF(A2="","",IF(A2>0,Sheet2!F9,""))